# Special characters in .blade.php on Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.6 in Windows and start to develop a system, but when I tried to write files '.blade.php' with special characters I got stuck. They only show '�'.

I saw many people saying the same thing that this other question https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81492/problema-com-caracteres-especiais-laravel but this didn't worked for me.

I also put this code on my base '.blade.php' file which I'm extending from the other one

```
!DOCTYPE html 

html lang="pt-br"

meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
 
content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: `html lang="pt-br` missing ending quote

Comment: check encoding in your database if you get data from

Comment: In your config/database.php, what charset and collation is set?

Comment: I can access the database, but the retrieving data is also showing wrong like a name "João Huel" is showed like "Jo\u00e3o Huel".
My charset in config/database.php is "utf8mb4" and the collation is "utf8mb4_unicode_ci".
My created database is in collation utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I fixed the problem, it was caused because the default encoding file of Eclipse IDE was conflicting with UTF8. So I changed it and it worked

Comment: What was the default? To what did you change it?

Comment: Cp1252, I'm using Eclipse Oxygen 4.7.2 2017